# smartAdServer siteid pageid formatid doesn't work with sdk smartAdServer

Tags: java, android

the client give me a association list of pageId formatid and a siteId, banner and intertitiel ad, for example

siteId: 57375  pageId: 430631  FormatId: 25146

but when i try to display this with the method

```
mInterstitialView.loadAd(57372, ""+pageId, formatId, true, "startup", interstitialResponseHandler);
```

it loads but shown nothing, i also try with demo available with adServerSdk it not work neither

The client say that this values are operational

```
interstitialResponseHandler =  new SASAdView.AdResponseHandler() {

        public void adLoadingFailed(Exception e) {
            Log.i("######## error", "###### error");
            // the Ad failed to load
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void adLoadingCompleted(SASAdElement paramSASAdElement) {
            Log.i("########Complete", "######Complete");

        }
};
```

i get this error on log cat

```
03-31 11:53:06.849: I/######## error(19322): ###### error
com.smartadserver.android.library.exception.SASNoAdToDeliverException: No ad to deliver or invalid ad request parameters
    at com.smartadserver.android.library.provider.http.SASHttpAdElementProvider$1.onSuccess(SASHttpAdElementProvider.java:107)
    at com.smartadserver.android.library.http.SASAsyncHttpClient$HttpRequestThread.run(SASAsyncHttpClient.java:169)
```

I try also without startup like this but i have the same error

```
mInterstitialView.loadAd(57372, ""+430631, 25146, true, "", interstitialResponseHandler);
```

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: are you sure your target string is correct? Maybe you should leave it blank istead of "startup" ? Also what do you do in the Response Handler? Could it be you somehow hide the view there, or something?

Comment: Thanks for your reponse i add response handler to my first message